# laravel-4 get entity based on related entity condition

Tags: orm, laravel-4, relational-database, eloquent

I'm trying to get a series of product entities where the related brand entity is a certain type.

eg. get all products (and related entities such as brand and gallery) where the brand entity has a $brand_slug of Dell.

I'm trying to use this query but getting no results.

```
Product::with(array('brand' => function($query) use ($brand_slug)
{
    $query->where('slug', '=', $brand_slug);
}
```

Could somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't completed the query.

```
Product::with(array('brand' => function($query) use ($brand_slug)
         {
            $query->where('slug', '=', $brand_slug);
         }
        ->get();
```

Comment: Sorry I missed out that instead of the ->get() method I call ->paginate(12). I'm not sure if this makes a difference?

Comment: Do you have relationship in Product model?

Comment: I do yes. A function that returns belongsTo('Brand')